# Можно ли использовать сокеты в gwt?

Tags: gwt, google-app-engine, java, java-ee

Можно ли сделать приложение на сокетах, используя gwt? И по возможности, укажите какие-нибудь в документации как это сделать и если нельзя то почему?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под приложением на сокетах? Возможность открывать сокеты на клиентской стороне?

Comment: На стороне сервера, когда я подключаю класс ServerSocket. То появляется сообщение: `SocketServer is not suported by GAE runtime environment`

Comment: А вам нужно именно GAE? Если нет, то просто нужно отключить GAE в опциях проекта.

Comment: На серверной стороне GWT приложения вы можете использовать все, что заблагорассудится. Это по сути обычный webapp.

Comment: А как запустить такое приложение без GAE?

Comment: Собрать обычный war-ник и развернуть на любой сервер приложений (Tomcat, Jetty и т.п.)

Comment: При сборке в eclipse с gwt-plugin используется ссылка такого вида `http://127.0.0.1:8888/BugCountGwt/BugCountGwt.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` У меня tomcat на порте 8080. Он работает, если ссылка такая `http://127.0.0.1:8080/BugCountGwt/BugCountGwt.html`, но как подключить code-server?

Comment: Вы все в кучу мешаете )

http://127.0.0.1:8888/BugCountGwt/BugCountGwt.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 - это ссылка на приложение запущенное в эклипсе в режиме DevMode. Грубо говоря, eclipse запускает сервер jetty на порту 8888, разворачивает на нем ваше приложение и запускает отладочный сервер на порту 9997. При этом весь js по-хитрому эмулируется и вы можете видеть изменения на клиентской стороне без перекомпиляции.

При развертывании на самостоятельный сервер приложений (тот же томкат) вы предварительно компилируете клиентскую часть. И для работы отладочный сервер уже будет не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде стало понятнее. А как можно отслеживать ошибки выполнения? Где смотреть стек?

Comment: Если вы про автономный режим, то стэктрэйсы, ошибки и прочее в томкате будут по-умолчанию валиться в log/catalina.out.

Но правило хорошего тона - использовать библиотеку логгирования (например  slf4j + log4j или slf4j + logback) и самому настраивать, что и куда выводить.

Answer (score 1):

на стороне клиента - если только вебсокеты использовать:

WebSockets for GWT

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-ws/

Ну а если на стороне сервера для сторонних приложений то без вопросов.